# Linux Filesystem with either no discretionary access control (user/group permissions) or that can have it disabled

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

Is there a file system for linux that has no permissions? I have a folder that is shared between multiple applications and although they are all running in the same group, I am constantly having permission problems with one application reading what another has written. Since I am using LVM and this is a separate volume, I can format or mount it in any way. I would like a file system that can ignore permissions: i.e. everything is readable and writable by every user on the machine.

Obviously in terms of security I have considered the impact and for my environment it is fine, particularly as it will only be the one partition.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the umask of the processes to 0 should cause those processes to create files with full read/write permissions, unless those processes take explicit action to limit the permissions (wrong IMHO if there's no configuration option to influence that).

You could contemplate use a VFAT filesystem, mounted with `-i umask=0` if your applications can handle the limitations of VFAT. As VFAT has no notion of users, this might work for you.

Comment: Great, I had tried setting the umask before with no luck but inspired by your answer I checked the configuration for that application and found it sets the umask within the program itself and I have now set that to 002. Hopefully that works, but will need to leave it running for a bit now to see if any problems occur. Would really like to avoid using FAT - to the extent where I would probably rather write a FUSE FS that forces permissions.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can set guid bit on the directory (and the default umask, that will give group-access for all), and that will cause all files and subdirectories, created in that directory to have group of the parent directory.

2) FAT? ;)

Comment: or exFAT? though I would prefer to just disable permissions on a more fully featured filesystem...